# Modbus RTU using Nmodbus in c#

Tags: c#, modbus

i wrote a simple code using NModbus library in visual studio.

Here is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3"))
    {
        // configure serial port
        port.BaudRate = 57600;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.Parity = Parity.Even;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.Open();

        // create modbus master
        IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);

        byte slaveId = byte.Parse(Slave.Text); ;
        ushort startAddress = ushort.Parse(StrtAdd.Text); ;
        //ushort[] registers = new ushort[] { 1, 2, 3 };
       // ushort[] registers = new ushort[] { 01, 05, 15 };
        // write three registers
      //  master.WriteMultipleRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, registers);
       ushort[] holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, 1);

       label3.Text = Convert.ToString(holding_register);
    }
```

Now the result I am getting in `lable3` is `System.UInt16[]`. How can I display the data from the holding register and display it on the label.

Comment: so `label3.Text = Convert.ToString(holding_register[0]);` doesn't give you the result?

Comment: I am feeling way to embarrassed now. I totally forgot that it's the array. Silly me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `label3.Text = Convert.ToString(holding_register[0]);`

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772162/handling-modbus-rtu-frame-in-c-sharp) related to it can you please see it ?